# how to truncate or shorten method?

Tags: android

I am new to android and oop programming. I just want to ask help on how do i shorten or more oop my code. i got this one method that to be called on a switch case scenario.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, bookCover);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            final int pos = position;
            share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(pos == 0) {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("name", "Brochure Nur1");
                        params.putString("caption", "This is a test for Brochure Nur.");
                        params.putString("description", "Brochure Nur is already available on android app!");
                        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
                        //params.putString("picture", "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10203610233686079&set=a.10203610230766006.1073741829.1523023247&type=1&theater");
                        params.putString("picture","https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

                        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
                                Session.getActiveSession(),
                                params))
                            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                    FacebookException error) {
                                    if (error == null) {
                                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                        // and the post Id.
                                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                        if (postId != null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Successfuly posted!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                        // User clicked the "x" button
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                            "Publish cancelled", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // Generic, ex: network error
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            "Error posting story", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }



                            })
                            .build();
                            feedDialog.show();



                    } 

                    if(pos == 1) {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("name", "Brochure Nur2");
                        params.putString("caption", "This is a test for Brochure Nur.");
                        params.putString("description", "Brochure Nur is already available on android app!");
                        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
                        //params.putString("picture", "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10203610233686079&set=a.10203610230766006.1073741829.1523023247&type=1&theater");
                        params.putString("picture","https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

                        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
                                Session.getActiveSession(),
                                params))
                            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                    FacebookException error) {
                                    if (error == null) {
                                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                        // and the post Id.
                                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                        if (postId != null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                "Successfuly posted!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                        // User clicked the "x" button
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                            "Publish cancelled", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // Generic, ex: network error
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            "Error posting story", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }



                            })
                            .build();
                            feedDialog.show();


                    }
```

is there a way i can make it shorter but functional?Because as much as possible i dont want to repeat codes.

Comment: what is share variable i mean is it button or what?

Comment: yes it is a button.i got this view pager, i got 3 diffent title, so when i click the share button it will get the approriate title